# Spark streaming receiver Out of Memory (OOM)

Tags: spark-streaming, receiver

I have a problem where the receiver restarts again and again.
I am using Spark 1.6.1.
I use Spark Streaming to receive from a streaming, then use map to deserialize pb data.

My testing contains two cases:

1. Just receive the data and print directly: the app is stable
2. Receive and deserialize: this produces problems. The occurrence time is not regular.
   There is 500Mb/min. I have set executor memory at 8GB. The problem is just like something allocate memory extremely. But, I don't know why.

My code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(args(8))
conf.set("spark.serializer",   "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
conf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled","true")
conf.set("spark.speculation","true")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(args(7).toInt))
val bigPipeStreams = (1 to args(3).toInt).map{
    i => ssc.networkStream(
    new MyBigpipeLogagentReceiver(args(0),args(1),args(2),i,args(4),args(5),args(6).toInt)
)
}
val lines = ssc.union(bigPipeStreams)   
def deserializePbData(value: String) : String = {

if (null == value || value.isEmpty) {
    return ""
}
var cuid = ""
var os = ""
var channel = ""
var sv = ""
var resid = ""
var appid = ""
var prod = ""
try { //if exception,useless data,just drop it
    val timeStrIndex = value.indexOf(",\"time_str\"")
    var strAfterTruncation = ""
    if (-1 != timeStrIndex) {
        strAfterTruncation = value.substring(0,timeStrIndex) + "}"
    } else {
        strAfterTruncation = value
    }
    val jsonData = JSONObject.fromObject(strAfterTruncation)
    //val jsonData = value.getAsJsonArray()
    val binBody = jsonData.getString("bin_body")
    val pbData = binBody.substring(1,binBody.length()-1).split(",").foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.empty[Byte])((b,a) => b +java.lang.Byte.parseByte(a)).drop(8).toArray
    Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).getRequest().getUrl().getUrlFields().getAutokvList().asScala.foreach(a => 
        a.getKey() match {
            case "cuid" => cuid += a.getValue()
            case "os" => os += a.getValue()
            case "channel" => channel += a.getValue()
            case "sv" => sv += a.getValue()
            case "resid" => resid += a.getValue()
            case "appid" => appid += a.getValue()
            case "prod" => prod += a.getValue()
            case _ => null
        }
    )
    val decodeCuid = URLDecoder.decode(cuid, "UTF-8")
    os = os.toLowerCase()
    if (os.matches("android(.*)")) {
        os = "android"
    } else if (os.matches("iphone(.*)")) {
        os = "iphone"
    } else if (os.matches("ipad(.*)")) {
        os = "ipad"
    } else if (os.matches("s60(.*)")) {
        os = "symbian"
    } else if (os.matches("wp7(.*)")) {
        os = "wp7"
    } else if (os.matches("wp(.*)")) {
        os = "wp"
    } else if (os.matches("tizen(.*)")) {
        os = "tizen"

    val ifHasLogid = Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).hasLogid()
    val time = Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).getTime()
    if (ifHasLogid) {
        val logid = Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).getLogid()
        if (logid.isEmpty || logid.toString().equals("-") || !resid.toString().equals("01") || channel.isEmpty |!appid.isEmpty || !prod.isEmpty) {
            ""
        } else {
            decodeCuid + "\001" + os + "\001" + channel + "\001" + sv + "\001" + "1" + "\001" + "1" + "\001" + time + "\n"
        }
    } else {
        ""
    }
} catch {
    case _:Throwable => ""
}
}
lines.map(parseData).print()
```

The error text:

```
016-07-12T12:00:01.546+0800: 5096.643: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 442499072 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(2356736K)] 5059009K->5059009K(7949312K), 0.0103342 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:01.556+0800: 5096.654: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(2356736K)] [ParOldGen:    5059009K->5057376K(5592576K)] 5059009K->5057376K(7949312K), [Metaspace: 44836K->44490K(1089536K)], 0.8769617 secs] [Times: user=17.88   sys=0.04, real=0.88 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:02.434+0800: 5097.531: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.2951974 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000662 seconds
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid24310.hprof ...
2016-07-12T12:00:30.960+0800: 5126.057: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 28.5260812 seconds, Stopping threads     took: 0.0000995 seconds
Heap dump file created [5211252802 bytes in 28.526 secs]
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 24310"...
2016-07-12T12:00:31.589+0800: 5126.686: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.6289627 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001258 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:31.595+0800: 5126.692: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004822 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001493 seconds
2016-07-12 12:00:31.597 [Thread-5] ERROR [Logging.scala:95] - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:155) ~[    spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:135) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString_slow(Output.java:420) ~[ spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString(Output.java:326) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:153) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:146) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568) ~[ spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:194) ~[ spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeAll(Serializer.scala:153) ~[    spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dataSerializeStream(BlockManager.scala:1196) ~[    spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.dataSerialize(BlockManager.scala:1202) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:858) ~[   spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:645) ~[ spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockManagerBasedBlockHandler.storeBlock(ReceivedBlockHandler.scala:77) ~[   spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushAndReportBlock(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:157) ~[   spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushArrayBuffer(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:128) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl$$anon$3.onPushBlock(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:109) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.pushBlock(BlockGenerator.scala:296) ~[    spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$receiver$BlockGenerator$$keepPushingBlocks(    BlockGenerator.scala:268) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator$$anon$1.run(BlockGenerator.scala:109) ~[  spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
2016-07-12 12:00:31.600 [SIGTERM handler] ERROR [SignalLogger.scala:57] - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-07-12T12:00:31.611+0800: 5126.708: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005602 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001765 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:31.617+0800: 5126.714: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004800 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001412 seconds
2016-07-12 12:00:32.483 [Bigpipe Receiver-SendThread(cq01-bigpipe-proxy01.cq01.baidu.com:2181)] WARN  [ClientCnxnSocket.java:139] -     Connected to an old server; r-o mode will be unavailable
2016-07-12T12:00:32.507+0800: 5127.604: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004604 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001198 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:32.509+0800: 5127.606: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002919 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001800 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:32.509+0800: 5127.607: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002692 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001612 seconds
2016-07-12 12:00:32.549 [Bigpipe Receiver-SendThread(tc-bigpipe-proxy03.tc.baidu.com:2181)] WARN  [ClientCnxnSocket.java:139] -     Connected to an old server; r-o mode will be unavailable
2016-07-12T12:00:34.220+0800: 5129.317: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 424148992 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1931776K->188775K(2363904K)] 6989152K->5246152K(7956480K), 0.2569385 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=5.19, real=0.26 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:34.477+0800: 5129.575: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2575019 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000384 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:35.478+0800: 5130.575: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002786 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000424 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:37.600+0800: 5132.697: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 482344960 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 2120551K->387013K(2268160K)] 7177928K->5444389K(7860736K), 0.5153031 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=9.89, real=0.52 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:38.116+0800: 5133.213: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.5157529 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000427 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:40.116+0800: 5135.213: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003171 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0001000 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:40.419+0800: 5135.516: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 599785472 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 2240965K->471033K(2324992K)] 7298341K->5633517K(7917568K), 0.3621433 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=7.11, real=0.36 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:40.781+0800: 5135.878: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.3626080 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000429 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:41.781+0800: 5136.879: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003301 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000947 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:43.108+0800: 5138.205: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 620756992 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 2324985K->378481K(2054656K)] 7487469K->5831048K(7647232K), 0.2593685 secs] [Times: user=0.66 sys=4.96, real=0.26 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:43.368+0800: 5138.465: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 378481K->0K(2054656K)] [ParOldGen:   5452566K->4713601K(5592576K)] 5831048K->4713601K(7647232K), [Metaspace: 44635K->44635K(1089536K)], 4.3137405 secs] [Times: user=9.78    sys=74.53, real=4.31 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:47.682+0800: 5142.779: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 4.5736603 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000449 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:47.682+0800: 5142.779: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002430 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000856 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:49.954+0800: 5145.052: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 597688320 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1583616K->161266K(2189824K)] 6297217K->4874867K(7782400K), 0.0388138 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.84, real=0.04 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:49.993+0800: 5145.091: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0392926 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000449 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:51.903+0800: 5147.000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 596115456 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1744882K->324587K(2213888K)] 6458483K->5038189K(7806464K), 0.0334029 secs] [Times: user=0.69 sys=0.03, real=0.04 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:51.936+0800: 5147.034: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0338707 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000404 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:53.942+0800: 5149.039: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 654835712 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1954795K->490438K(2120704K)] 6668397K->5204039K(7713280K), 0.0441762 secs] [Times: user=0.95 sys=0.02, real=0.05 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:53.986+0800: 5149.083: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0446174 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000456 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:56.102+0800: 5151.199: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 763887616 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 2120646K->639467K(1943552K)] 6834247K->5370280K(7536128K), 0.1124828 secs] [Times: user=1.07 sys=1.30, real=0.11 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:56.214+0800: 5151.312: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1129348 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000396 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:57.784+0800: 5152.881: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 895483904 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1943531K->745977K(2050048K)] 6674344K->5504073K(7642624K), 0.0971717 secs] [Times: user=1.20 sys=0.67, real=0.10 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:57.881+0800: 5152.979: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0977363 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000941 seconds
2016-07-12T12:00:59.406+0800: 5154.504: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 935329792 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 2050041K->599188K(1715200K)] 6808137K->5647517K(7307776K), 0.3651465 secs] [Times: user=0.98 sys=5.88, real=0.37 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:00:59.772+0800: 5154.869: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.3656089 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000479 seconds
2016-07-12T12:01:00.968+0800: 5156.066: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 954204160 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1568404K->697830K(1667072K)] 6616733K->5746159K(7259648K), 0.0978955 secs] [Times: user=1.91 sys=0.04, real=0.09 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:01:01.066+0800: 5156.164: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0983759 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000482 seconds
2016-07-12T12:01:02.189+0800: 5157.287: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 954204160 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 1667046K->465454K(1864192K)] 6715375K->5855655K(7456768K), 0.1261993 secs] [Times: user=2.41 sys=0.29, real=0.12 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:01:02.316+0800: 5157.413: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 465454K->65236K(1864192K)] [ParOldGen:   5390200K->5592328K(5592576K)] 5855655K->5657564K(7456768K), [Metaspace: 44635K->44635K(1089536K)], 3.2729437 secs] [Times: user=12.34   sys=57.11, real=3.28 secs] 
2016-07-12T12:01:05.589+0800: 5160.686: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 3.3998619 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000521 seconds
2016-07-12T12:01:05.589+0800: 5160.686: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002330 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000949 seconds
2016-07-12T12:01:05.688+0800: 5160.785: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002935 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000514 seconds
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1864192K, used 146620K [0x0000000715580000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 932352K, 8% used [0x0000000715580000,0x000000071a4fa138,0x000000074e400000)
  from space 931840K, 7% used [0x0000000787200000,0x000000078b1b5290,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 931840K, 0% used [0x000000074e400000,0x000000074e400000,0x0000000787200000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 5592328K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x0000000715580000, 0x0000000715580000)
  object space 5592576K, 99% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000007155420a8,0x0000000715580000)
 Metaspace       used 44654K, capacity 44990K, committed 45864K, reserved 1089536K
  class space    used 6212K, capacity 6324K, committed 6440K, reserved 1048576K
```

New Error: I think it's the upload error which call oom problem.I'd like to know how to fix this upload error?

```
    2016-07-15 11:41:47.307 [shuffle-client-0] ERROR [TransportChannelHandler.java:128] - Connection to     nmg01-taihang-d10207.nmg01.baidu.com/10.76.48.22:30456 has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming  connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong.
2016-07-15 11:41:47.309 [shuffle-client-0] ERROR [TransportResponseHandler.java:122] - Still have 1 requests outstanding when   connection from nmg01-taihang-d10207.nmg01.baidu.com/10.76.48.22:30456 is closed
2016-07-15 11:41:47.314 [shuffle-client-0] ERROR [Logging.scala:95] - Error while uploading block input-0-1468553896200
java.io.IOException: Connection from nmg01-taihang-d10207.nmg01.baidu.com/10.76.48.22:30456 closed
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111) [spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
2016-07-15T11:41:47.316+0800: 2176.487: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002632 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000521 seconds
2016-07-15 11:41:47.316 [Thread-5] WARN  [Logging.scala:91] - Failed to replicate input-0-1468553896200 to BlockManagerId(2,    nmg01-taihang-d10207.nmg01.baidu.com, 30456), failure #0
java.io.IOException: Connection from nmg01-taihang-d10207.nmg01.baidu.com/10.76.48.22:30456 closed
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111) ~[spark-assembly-1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.5.1.3-baidu-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.6.1.0-baidu-SNAPSHOT]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
2016-07-15T11:41:48.316+0800: 2177.487: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003391 seconds, Stopping threads  took: 0.0000979 seconds
2016-07-15T11:41:51.312+0800: 2180.483: [GC (Allocation Failure) --[PSYoungGen: 2894863K->2894863K(3007488K)]   8299519K->9550273K(9998336K), 0.7462118 secs] [Times: user=9.78 sys=0.02, real=0.74 secs] 
2016-07-15T11:41:52.059+0800: 2181.230: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 2894863K->0K(3007488K)] [ParOldGen:  6655410K->6895736K(6990848K)] 9550273K->6895736K(9998336K), [Metaspace: 44409K->44409K(1087488K)], 0.4061892 secs] [Times: user=7.50    sys=0.01, real=0.41 secs]
```

Comment: @XBin, Please *do not* include the error information as *only* a screenshot. People can not search for the text in a Screensot. It is usually much harder to read. To include the error, please include the actual text of the error, copied as text and formatted in a code block. If having a screenshot of the error provides additional information beyond the plain text to people reading the question, then do include one *in addition to* copying the error text into the question.

Comment: Without code, a [mcve], this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: *How to create a [mcve], [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  That means enough code that *completely* reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i am attaching code and log file.

Comment: @XBin, You should [edit] your Question to add any additional information. The additional information should **not** be placed as *Answers* to your question. Stack Exchange has a Question --> Answer format. Any information that affects how the Question is framed should be placed in the Question. While a response to a request for more information might be first made in a comment, the additional information should be edited into the Question. Questions should be maintained to contain all information needed to completely understand the issue enabling anyone to provide an Answer. [cont]

Comment: @Xbin, Such information should never be placed in Answers. There is a normal methodology for Answers which are not actually answers to the Question to be deleted.

Comment: @XBin, BTW: If you want a specific person to be notified of your comment, you need to include their ID in your comment with an `@` in front of it. For instance, for me it would be `@Makyen`. If you do this as the first thing in your comment the system will provide auto-complete suggestions. The original poster of the answer/question on which you are commenting will always be notified. This [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/271271) has more information. It is a good idea to get in the habit of using `@` to direct comments.

Comment: @Xbin, I moved your error text and code into the question.  In the process of re-indenting your code to reflect its structure as written, I have found what appears to be an error. Your `else if` statement `} else if (os.matches("tizen(.*)")) {os = "tizen"` opens a block, but the block appears to not be closed where it "should". It is currently closed by ` } catch {`. This may be the error that is causing your problem, or it might be just an error in your copying the code to this site. If it is an error in copying, please correct it. If it is your actual error, I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to have an error in structure.  In the process of looking at your code (to re-indenting it to reflect the structure as posted), I found that your last `else if` statement:

```
} else if (os.matches("tizen(.*)")) {
    os = "tizen"
```

opens a block, but does not close the block where it "should". Instead, the block is actually terminated with:

```
} catch {
```

The full code as it appears was intended (and re-indented) is:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(args(8))
conf.set("spark.serializer",   "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
conf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled","true")
conf.set("spark.speculation","true")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(args(7).toInt))
val bigPipeStreams = (1 to args(3).toInt).map{
    i => ssc.networkStream(
        new MyBigpipeLogagentReceiver(args(0),args(1),args(2),i,args(4),args(5),args(6).toInt)
    )
}
val lines = ssc.union(bigPipeStreams)   
def deserializePbData(value: String) : String = {

    if (null == value || value.isEmpty) {
        return ""
    }
    var cuid = ""
    var os = ""
    var channel = ""
    var sv = ""
    var resid = ""
    var appid = ""
    var prod = ""
    try { //if exception,useless data,just drop it
        val timeStrIndex = value.indexOf(",\"time_str\"")
        var strAfterTruncation = ""
        if (-1 != timeStrIndex) {
            strAfterTruncation = value.substring(0,timeStrIndex) + "}"
        } else {
            strAfterTruncation = value
        }
        val jsonData = JSONObject.fromObject(strAfterTruncation)
        //val jsonData = value.getAsJsonArray()
        val binBody = jsonData.getString("bin_body")
        val pbData = binBody.substring(1,binBody.length()-1).split(",").foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.empty[Byte])((b,a) => b +java.lang.Byte.parseByte(a)).drop(8).toArray
        Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).getRequest().getUrl().getUrlFields().getAutokvList().asScala.foreach(a => 
            a.getKey() match {
                case "cuid" => cuid += a.getValue()
                case "os" => os += a.getValue()
                case "channel" => channel += a.getValue()
                case "sv" => sv += a.getValue()
                case "resid" => resid += a.getValue()
                case "appid" => appid += a.getValue()
                case "prod" => prod += a.getValue()
                case _ => null
            }
        )
        val decodeCuid = URLDecoder.decode(cuid, "UTF-8")
        os = os.toLowerCase()
        if (os.matches("android(.*)")) {
            os = "android"
        } else if (os.matches("iphone(.*)")) {
            os = "iphone"
        } else if (os.matches("ipad(.*)")) {
            os = "ipad"
        } else if (os.matches("s60(.*)")) {
            os = "symbian"
        } else if (os.matches("wp7(.*)")) {
            os = "wp7"
        } else if (os.matches("wp(.*)")) {
            os = "wp"
        } else if (os.matches("tizen(.*)")) {
            os = "tizen"
        }

        val ifHasLogid = Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).hasLogid()
        val time = Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).getTime()
        if (ifHasLogid) {
            val logid = Lighttpd.lighttpd_log.parseFrom(pbData).getLogid()
            if (logid.isEmpty || logid.toString().equals("-") || !resid.toString().equals("01") || channel.isEmpty |!appid.isEmpty || !prod.isEmpty) {
                ""
            } else {
                decodeCuid + "\001" + os + "\001" + channel + "\001" + sv + "\001" + "1" + "\001" + "1" + "\001" + time + "\n"
            }
        } else {
            ""
        }
    } catch {
        case _:Throwable => ""
    }
}
lines.map(parseData).print()
```

I have not checked your code for functionality. This is just a syntax/structure issue that stood out when very briefly looking at your the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry about put question in answer. First question in stackflow.

Comment: About not close the block, it is a copy error. My code have closed it.